# How to run sql-client against yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/sqlClient.html,
looks that it illustrates the sql-client functionalities with the standalone cluster.

I would ask whether sql client supports to run against yarn cluster? If yes, I would ask how to do the configuration, I didn't find related how-to on flink.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a yarn cluster available to test this with, but see [FLINK-18273](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18273) which explains that

> The SQL Client YAML has a deployment section. One can use the regular flink run options there and configure e.g. a YARN job session cluster. This is neither tested nor documented but should work due to the architecture.

and also mentions that

> The deployment section has also problems with keys that use upper cases. E.g. `fromsavepoint` != `fromSavepoint` which requires to use the short option `s` as a workaround.

Putting those two statements together suggests that putting this entry into `sql-env.yaml` (xxx is the yarn application id):

```yaml
deployment:
  yid: xxx
```

and then starting the client via `sql-client embedded -e sql-env.yaml` might just work.

See also https://docs.cloudera.com/csa/1.2.0/sql-client/topics/csa-sql-client-session-config.html.